# Am I supposed to granularly configure recaptcha in all places of a webapp?

Tags: captcha, bot

I am trying to understand how to properly configure things like Google RecaptchaV3.

I have configured it manually for just one of tens of the views in my webapp so it sends a token to backend and backend sends a request to google to verify it and then performs the requested action to the client or sends an error like "You seem to be a bot".

I know I am the only one who is responsible for the security of the webapp. So, is this supposed to include this logic into every single action on the client side I want to protect from bots and the same for backend endpoints?

Comment: Typically, you place the captcha at an authentication point with the understanding that all other actions that use authentication have passed the captcha, too.

Comment: haven't looked at the current recaptcha lately, but they used to recommend putting it on as many pages as possible.  That would increase the accuracy of the results as they gather more analytics about the user behavior to determine bot or not.  See here: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#placement_on_your_website